# MySQL query to find an exact match in ANY field of a table

Tags: php, mysql

I build a MySQL query at runtime with this

```
$search = "needle";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ( (1=0) ";
for($i=0; $i<count($names); ++$i) {
    $sql .= " OR (`{$names[$i]}` = '$search') ";
}
$sql .= ") ";
```

where `names` is an array with all the column names. The query seems fine to me:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ( (1=0) OR (`img` = 'needle') OR (`title` = 'needle') OR (`name_en` = 'needle') OR (`caption_en` = 'needle') OR (`bottom_en` = 'needle') )
```

But the problem is... It finds A LOT of rows **EVEN IF NONE OF THEM** exactly contain the 'needle' string.
Some of them contain it, but in the middle of a text field for example, but even the number of results doesn't make sense. Just four out of 103 contain the needle, but I get 60 rows back!
And again, I was expecting ZERO rows, since NONE OF THEM are EQUAL to 'needle'.

Is there something stupid I am missing?

Comment: I don't see anything "stupid" in your code or query. It is likely the cause of your problem is somewhere else. Oh, that is, apart from the insertion of the PHP variable into the query. It is better to use parameter binding for `$search`. But this is not causing the problem you describe.

Comment: I will try to extract the data and post it here. It's driving me nuts. Even running the query directly in MySQL gives me back a lot of rows which DO NOT CONTAIN the needle. Ok, it's almost midnight but...

Comment: You could try to create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: Are these columns integer columns? It's probably mapping `'$search'` to 0 while doing an integer comparison.

Comment: @KIKO Software thank you, I knew JSfiddle, not sqlfiddle :) Bill Karwin, that's a wonderful tip, I didn't think of it. Most of them are strings but one or two are integer so... Let me check!

Comment: @BillKarwin please write it as an answer so I can accept it. I had ONE integer field, I tried SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE (sortOrder=0) and... Guess how many... 60! So it was counting the matches between the integer fields and the needle string... So, yes, it was stupid from my side :(

Comment: @BillKarwin Ah, yes, that was a good catch. I simply assumed they were all TEXT types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments above, it was revealed that one column in the table is an integer.

Comparing an integer to a string results in mapping the string to its integer value, i.e. any leading digits are used, and non-digits are ignored. If there are no leading digits, the integer value of the search string is 0.

Therefore it would match any row where the integer column is 0.